# Do reinterpret_cast double* to unsigned long long* constitue a strict aliasing violation?

Tags: c++, serialization, c++17, strict-aliasing

To give some context, I'm focusing the case of data serialization/deserialization **without being dependent of the platform endianness**.

For integral types, we can use the bitwise-shifting operators for that purpose (since they already abstract the system endianness for us).

But in the case of floating-point types, the bitwise-shifting operators are not available (which is a shame IMHO but it's pointless to discuss it).

I was wondering if it is legal to interpret a `double` value as `unsigned long long` (assuming both have the same size) and operate the serialization/deserialization operation from it.

For example:

```
// REQUIREMENTS:
// - I want to serialize the data in big-endian (no matter what is the system endianness)
// - buff size >= sizeof(double)
void serialize(unsigned char * buff, double value)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(unsigned long long));

    unsigned long long val = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(&value);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(double); ++i)
        buff[sizeof(double)-1-i] = val >> (i*CHAR_BIT);
}
```

But I suspect such workaround to be undefined behaviour (due to strict aliasing violation). I'm wondering if it is still possible to perform such serialization of floating-point values **without sacrificing portability**.

I know I could `reinterpret_cast` directly into an `unsigned char *` but then I would need to check the system endianness to properly handle the data, which I want to avoid (if I can).

***PS:** I know the simplest way would be to send data as text instead (but it's out of the topic here)*

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255333/discussion-on-question-by-fareanor-do-reinterpret-cast-double-to-unsigned-long); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.